# Use of Chain rule in PDE problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, chain-rule

We study the one dimensional heat equation

$$u_{t}(x, t) = u_{xx}(x, t), \quad x \in \mathbb{R}, t> 0.$$

I our textbook, in order to prove that the solution is a function of one variable, they define a function

$$v(x, t) = u(cx, c^2t)$$

for a $c > 0$ and claims

$$v_t = c^2 u_t \quad \text{and} \quad v_{xx} = c^2 u_{xx}.$$

This is probably completely trivial, but I fail to see how they have applied the chain rule here. Here is my reasoning. If we let $\phi_1 = cx$ and $\phi_2 = c^2 t$, we can apply the chain rule to find $v_t$ as follows:

$$v_t = \frac{\partial u}{\partial \phi_1}\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial \phi_2}\frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial t} = c^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial \phi_2}.$$

What I don't quite understand is how $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \phi_2}$, the partial with respect to $\phi_2 = c^2 t$, is equal to $u_t = \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us use the following notation. Suppose $u(X, T)$ solves the heat equation, i.e.
\begin{align}
u_{T}(a, b)= u_{XX}(a, b).
\end{align}
for any $(a, b) \in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$.

Now, consider
\begin{align}
v(x, t) = u(cx, c^2t)
\end{align}
i.e. set $X = cx$ and $T = c^2t$. Then we see that
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial T}\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = c^2u_T(cx, c^2t) 
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} =  \frac{\partial u}{\partial X}\frac{\partial X}{\partial x} = cu_X(cx, c^2t)
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(cu_X(cx, c^2t)) = c^2u_{XX}(cx, c^2t).
\end{align}
Hence we have that
\begin{align}
v_t-v_{xx} = c^2\left(u_T(cx, c^2t)-u_{XX}(cx, c^2t)\right) = 0.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! This made it clearer. I guess I just though about the substitution abit "inside out".